# How can I find out on which page of Google's search results my site appears?

Tags: search

My website "http://www.cpcells.com" is related to computer cells. So when I enter "computer cells" in Google search, my page maybe appear in the 12112th page of results. Is there an easy way to know where exactly my page appears? (The 10th page or 30th page etc.)

Answer (score 9):

You can use this site

http://WhatPageOfGoogleAmIOn.com/

---

For example; for the search *"Cambridge Cells"* the site *"www.cpcells.com"* is on page **9**

---

Is important to know, that Google does not serve more than 1000 results per query, therefore is unlikely you will find your page if it is located after the 100th page.